# Angular Bootstrap datepicker too narrow

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I've followed the demo on the [Angular UI boostrap page](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to add a datepicker to my Django site. 
I included the following files:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/angular.js' %}" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-switch.js' %}" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/angular-bootstrap-switch.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/bsSwitch.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/angular-locale_pl-pl.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.0.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/gabinet.js' %}"></script>
```

I added this html code:

```
 <h4>Wybierz miesiąc</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
           <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{[{format}]}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" ng-required="true" show-button-bar="false" datepicker-popup="mediumDate" show-weeks="false" datepicker-popup="yyyy-mm"/>
               <span class="input-group-btn">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
               </span>
            </p>
         </div>
     </div>
```

In the controller I setup the relevant data for this datepicker. 
The problem is in the pop-up: it's simply too narrow to display the whole calendar!

[image]

Why is that and what would be the best way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

The German language is on the average "verbose" or in other words, needs more screen real estate space when compared to English.

Did you try to change your containing div to col-md-4 ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but the size of the div is not related, the width of the pop-out calendar stays the same and is simply too narrow.